# Why is "this" pointing to the "window Object" in the callback function?

Tags: javascript, callback, this

```
var callBackFunc = {
    value       : "CallBackValue",
    getValue    : function(callback) {
        callback();
    }   
}
var TestingFunc = {
    value       : "TestingValue",
    alertValue  : function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}

$(function() {
    callBackFunc.getValue(TestingFunc.alertValue);
});
```

I don't want answers to be able to use it properly, but I wonder why "this" points to Window Objects. Plz... Help me!!

Comment: you can `bind` to the current function or objet, it's one way to make this refer to what you want.

Comment: its the global context, you should start off reading this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because `arguments` passed by `value` which means

`callBackFunc.getValue(TestingFunc.alertValue);`

equals to

```
callBackFunc.getValue(function() {
        console.log(this);
    });
```

so ,`callback()` works

```
(function() {
            console.log(this);
        })()
```

so ,you get `window`.

If `arguments` passed by `name` ,in this case `name` is `TestingFunc.alertValue`,then you will get what you want like :

`callback()` equals to `TestingFunc.alertValue()`

However,`js` works by `value` not `name`

Answer (score 0):

The plain callback function reference is passed as a parameter to the `callBackFunc.getValue`, so there is no current `this` context will be formed with the plain function and the default `this` leads to the global object (window).

In order to form the context, we can use `call, bind, apply` methods.